# Most reliable way to download files 1 at a time, using .NET methods?

Tags: c#, .net, download, webclient

I'm facing an issue with WebClient.DownloadFile() where it consistently downloads files incorrectly on a slow connection. By downloading incorrectly, I mean the size of the file in bytes does not match the expected size. It downloads fine on a normal ethernet connection. Here's the code:

```
internal void Start(List<FileInformation> fileList)
{
    filesCompleted = 0;
    totalNumberFiles = fileList.Count;

    using (webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        foreach (var file in fileList.OrderBy(x => x.Name))
        {
            if (file.Size > 0)
            {
                DownloadFile(file);
            }
            else
            {
                File.Create(AppStrings.FilebinPath + file.Name);
            }

            filesCompleted++;
            UpdateProgress(Convert.ToDouble(((filesCompleted / (double)totalNumberFiles) * 100).ToString("N2")));
        }
    }
}

private void DownloadFile(FileInformation file)
{
    var filePath = AppStrings.FilebinPath + file.Name;
    webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(AppStrings.FilebinServer + file.Name), filePath);

    //Recursively retry the download until it downloads correctly.
    if ((new FileInfo(filePath).Length != file.Size))
    {
        //Added this debugging info to figure out what is going wrong.
        AppLog.WriteError("Failed to download file: " + filePath + "\nSize downloaded: " + new FileInfo(filePath).Length + "\nCorrect size: " + file.Size);
        DownloadFile(file);
    }
}
```

For slow network connections, is there a more reliable way to do this?

EDIT: This is not a duplicate because the question is about downloading files synchronously and it asks what the most reliable way to do this is. The other topic is asking why DownloadFilesAsync fails to download files correctly.

EDIT 2: Tried the following code and got the same behavior as described in my first comment @David:

```
byte[] data = null;
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(AppStrings.FilebinServer + file.Name));
webRequest.ProtocolVersion = Version.Parse("1.0");
using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (var streamReader = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        data = new byte[(int)webResponse.ContentLength];

        for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = Convert.ToByte(streamReader.ReadByte());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you worried about `asyc` vs the current way you are doing it..? also UpdateProgress what's that method look like..?

Comment: Look at chunked HTTP downloads.

Comment: I'm not worried about async downloads so much. At this point I'd rather do the downloads one at a time, making sure that each file downloaded is valid before moving on to the next. UpdateProgress is an Action<double> event. It updates the main gui thread with the progress percentage.

Comment: On the slow connnection, does the file downloading work if you use a regular browser instead?  It could be a problem outside of the WebClient class.

Comment: @David I know this doesn't answer your question exactly, but I tested it on both network connections using the same IP address (bypassing the load balancer) so I know it's trying to get the same file. Instead of DownloadFile() I used DownloadData(). I noticed that on the fast network it consistently downloaded 2671 bytes, which is correct. On the slow network, it consistently downloaded 2108 bytes, which is incorrect. I'm not sure why the slow network would consistently download the same number of bytes if it's a connection issue.